# Can anyone tell me why Tkinter won't run on VS Code?

Tags: python, tkinter, visual-studio-code, pycharm

So I'm trying to get familiar with Tkinter and for some reason when I any code with tkinter imported into VS Code it get the following error.

[image: Tkinter error]

I realize it tells me my Python might not be configure for Tk, but i'm running the latest python version and to my understanding it comes with Tk already.

I've ran this code in PyCharm and it works fine.

Can anyone explain or tell me how I can get it to work in VS Code?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code and error messages.

Comment: From the error, it is looking for tkinter module inside a virtual environment created by Python 3.7.3.  But the version indicated in vscode status bar is 3.8.2.

Comment: I've changed the Indicated version but still no luck. I'm not sure how to fix it, but thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a Debian-based Linux distro like Ubuntu and using the Python that comes installed on your operating system? If so then you need to explicitly install tkinter as it is packaged separately from Python on Debian (same goes for pip).